# Create new vars without copy paste old var name

Tags: r

Sometimes when renaming variables the variable name can be long, for instance if it was from questionaire exported using excel, where the variable name is the entire question.

These can be frustrating to handle, they may not fully copy, you may not copy correctly etc.

Here is my way of handling this problem. Feel free to comment a better way:

```
library(tidyverse) 
   
data <- data.frame( "please tell us what your age is?" = c(24, 35, 46, 14 ),
            "what is your sex?" = c("male", "female", "male", "female"))

data

# create an "age" var and a "sex" var

data <- data %>% rename("age" = names(data)[1])
data <- data %>% rename("sex" = names(data)[2])

data
```

this makes the renaming of variables up to numbers which are more difficult to get wrong, and the variable name you would like.

Can anyone improve on this? such as an iteration?

Comment: This is not an answer really, but you may want to look at the `janitor::clean_names()` function. It won't make the var names shorter, but a little easier to work with by changing e.g. spaces into underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter **.name_repair** from the `tibble` function in the *tibble* package. It has different options that allow you to treat with problematic column names, such as the following ones.
(*Note:* In these examples, I've added some new columns just for notice the differences.)

```
data <-
  data.frame(
    "please tell us what your age is?" = c(24, 35, 46, 14),
    "what is your sex?" = c("male", "female", "male", "female"),
    "what is your sex?" = c(1, 0, 1, 0),
    x = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
    x = c(8, 90, 23, 45),
    check.names = FALSE
  )
```

- **minimal**: No name repair or checks, beyond basic existence.

```
> tibble(data, .name_repair = "minimal")
> tibble(data, .name_repair = "minimal")
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  `please tell us what your age is?` `what is your sex?` `what is your sex?`     x     x
                               <dbl> <chr>                             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1                                 24 male                                  1     0     8
2                                 35 female                                0     1    90
3                                 46 male                                  1     2    23
4                                 14 female                                0     3    45
```

- **unique**: Make sure names are unique and not empty.

```
> tibble(data, .name_repair = "unique")
New names:
• `what is your sex?` -> `what is your sex?...2`
• `what is your sex?` -> `what is your sex?...3`
• `x` -> `x...4`
• `x` -> `x...5`
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  `please tell us what your age is?` `what is your sex?...2` `what is your sex?...3` x...4 x...5
                               <dbl> <chr>                                     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1                                 24 male                                          1     0     8
2                                 35 female                                        0     1    90
3                                 46 male                                          1     2    23
4                                 14 female                                        0     3    45
```

- **check_unique**: (default value), no name repair, but check they are unique,

```
> tibble(data, .name_repair = "check_unique")

Error:
! Column names `what is your sex?` and `x` must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names must be unique.
✖ These names are duplicated:
  * "what is your sex?" at locations 2 and 3.
  * "x" at locations 4 and 5.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

- **universal**: Make the names unique and syntactic

```
> tibble(data, .name_repair = "universal")
New names:
• `please tell us what your age is?` -> `please.tell.us.what.your.age.is.`
• `what is your sex?` -> `what.is.your.sex....2`
• `what is your sex?` -> `what.is.your.sex....3`
• `x` -> `x...4`
• `x` -> `x...5`
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  please.tell.us.what.your.age.is. what.is.your.sex....2 what.is.your.sex....3 x...4 x...5
                             <dbl> <chr>                                 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1                               24 male                                      1     0     8
2                               35 female                                    0     1    90
3                               46 male                                      1     2    23
4                               14 female                                    0     3    45
```

- ...

See `help(tibble::tibble)` for more information.